# How to loop over subsets of length k of a list of length n in R?

Tags: r, for-loop, subset-sum

I am given two numbers `n` and `k` with `0 < k < n`.
How can I loop over all possible combinations of subsets of length k?

E.g. I have `x <- 1:10`.
Then I want to do

```
for (y in c(c(1,2,3), c(1,2,4), c(1,2,5), ..., c(8, 9, 10))){
   ...
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `combn` to get an array of all the subsets, then convert that into a list using `asplit`. Just iterate along this list.

For example, the following code will print out all the length-3 subsets of x:

```r
x <- 1:10
n <- 10
k <- 3

subsets <- asplit(combn(n, k), 2)

for(i in subsets) {
  print(x[i])
}
```